# Jquery does not scroll to an element

Tags: jquery

Thats my pen:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/EAfFD

I expect from jquery to scroll to the element with id4, but nothing happens.

Why?

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="id1" style="height:400px;background:blue;"></div>
  <div id="id2" style="height:400px;background:red;"></div>
  <div id="id3" style="height:400px;background:green;"></div>
  <div id="id4" style="height:400px;background:orange;"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

 var container = $('#container');
 var scrollTo = $('#id4');

container.animate({scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top  - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
            });
});
```

Comment: have you checked console for possible errors.?

Comment: @DevangRathod The OP didn't include jQuery.

Comment: There is jquery included it just does not scroll ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var container = $('html,body');
var scrollTo = $('#id4');
container.animate({
        scrollTop:scrollTo.position().top
}, 'slow');
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnAQs/)

Comment: You were the first. That $('html,body'); did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're trying to execute gives the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

This means that jQuery is not included.

If that doesn't fix it, also try changing

```
container.animate(
{
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top  - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});
```

to

```
$('html, body').animate(
{
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top  - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eKLv4/).